# Calling objects inside for loops in R using i

Tags: r, for-loop, object, variables, iteration

So stuck with a small problem while coding in R.

```
#R Code beigns
a_rolled <- load("/file1.Rdata")
b_rolled <- load("/file2.Rdata")
a_data <- load("/file3.Rdata")
b_data <- load("/file4.Rdata")

for(ii in c("a","b"))
{

temp1 <- merge(as.name(paste0(ii, "_rolled")), as.name(paste0(ii, "_data")), by="ID", all.x=T)
assign(paste0(ii,"_final"),value=temp1)

}

save(a_final,"/file5.Rdata")
save(b_final,"/file5.Rdata")
```

Since I want to call the data dynamically based on "i" values of the loop & merge them, is there a way to do this? As as.names() will not work in these situations, Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mget` to get data from string to actual object and use `Map` to `merge` them.

```
vec <- c("a","b")

result_data <- Map(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by='ID', all.x=TRUE), 
                   mget(paste0(vec, '_rolled')), mget(paste0(vec, '_data')))
```

This will return you list of dataframes, if you want them in separate dataframes, we can rename the list and use `list2env`.

```
names(result_data) <- paste0(vec, '_final')
list2env(result_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Now, you'll have `a_final` and `b_final` in your global environment.